# New secondary index based on column value (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame:

| index1 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12719 | row1 |
| 1 | 12719 | row2 |
| 2 | 12719 | row3 |
| 3 | 12719 | row4 |
| 4 | 20000 | row1 |
| 5 | 20000 | row2 |
| 6 | 20000 | row3 |
| 7 | 20000 | row4 |
| 8 | 20000 | row5 |

And I wanted to have a new column `index2` based on the occurrence (running number) of `col1` value:

| index1 | index2 | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 12719 | row1 |
| 1 | 1 | 12719 | row2 |
| 2 | 2 | 12719 | row3 |
| 3 | 3 | 12719 | row4 |
| 4 | 0 | 20000 | row1 |
| 5 | 1 | 20000 | row2 |
| 6 | 2 | 20000 | row3 |
| 7 | 3 | 20000 | row4 |
| 8 | 4 | 20000 | row5 |

I have tried a different combination of regex but just can't fit in my case.

Comment: `df['index2'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to generate the values of second index and set it as the second index by [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with parameter `append=True`.

```
df['index2'] = df.groupby('col1').cumcount()
df = df.set_index('index2', append=True)
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

           col1  col2
  index2             
0 0       12719  row1
1 1       12719  row2
2 2       12719  row3
3 3       12719  row4
4 0       20000  row1
5 1       20000  row2
6 2       20000  row3
7 3       20000  row4
8 4       20000  row5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the index

```
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.index,df.groupby('col1').cumcount()])
df
Out[77]: 
           col1  col2
index1               
0      0  12719  row1
1      1  12719  row2
2      2  12719  row3
3      3  12719  row4
4      0  20000  row1
5      1  20000  row2
6      2  20000  row3
7      3  20000  row4
8      4  20000  row5
```